# How do I update a Class object's attribute every time the Class object is interacted with?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have a class:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Book:
    def __init__(self, contents):
        self.last_accessed = datetime.now()
        self.content = contents
    
    def add_content(self, addition):
        self.content += str(addition)
        
    def replace_content(self, replacement):
        self.content = replacement
        
    def read_content(self):
        return self.content
```

I want this class to be able to record down when the Book is last accessed, for example:

```
Mybook = Book("Hello")  # Last accessed = datetime.now()
Mybook.add_content(" World")  # Last accessed = datetime.now(), which should be later than the previous datetime.now()
Mybook.read_content() # Last accessed should be later than when I added " World" to Mybook.content
```

How can I make it so that Mybook.last_accessed changes every time I make changes to Mybook?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `self.last_accessed = datetime.now()` to `add_content` etc. methods…?

Comment: What is the part of your code that changes `Mybook.last_accessed` the first time? What are the parts of your code that cause "changes to Mybook"? Can you think of a way to make the former run when the latter does?

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

class Book:
    def __init__(self, contents):
        self.__update_datetime()
        self.content = contents

    def __update_datetime(self):
        self.last_accessed = datetime.now()

    def add_content(self, addition):
        self.content += str(addition)
        self.__update_datetime()
    
    def replace_content(self, replacement):
        self.content = replacement
        self.__update_datetime()

    
    def read_content(self):
        self.__update_datetime()
        return self.content


Mybook = Book("Hello")
print(Mybook.last_accessed) # 2020-07-03 10:17:25.596847
Mybook.add_content(" World")
print(Mybook.last_accessed) # 2020-07-03 10:17:25.596905
Mybook.read_content()
print(Mybook.last_accessed) # 2020-07-03 10:17:25.596917
```

Comment: why use `__update_datetime`? Why double-underscore name-mangling? Just use a single underscore. ut yes, this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution could be to leverage decorators.

The following function can be used as a decorator, since it is a function that takes a function as a single argument, and returns another function.

```
def set_time(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_set_time(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.last_accessed = datetime.now()
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper_set_time
```

This allows to do things before and/or after the decorated function is called.

In your particular case, the decorated function will automatically execute `self.last_accessed = datetime.now()` before doing its computation.

This is how you decorate the methods of your `Book` class:

```
class Book:

    # Don't use @set_time for linters
    def __init__(self, contents):
        self.last_accessed = datetime.now()
        self.content = contents

    @set_time
    def add_content(self, addition):
        self.content += str(addition)

    @set_time
    def replace_content(self, replacement):
        self.content = replacement

    @set_time
    def read_content(self):
        return self.content
```

You see, it just costs to add a `@set_time` before methods definitions.

Note that we are not decorating the `__init__` method, this is just for linters not to complain about accessing the `.last_accessed` attributes of instances of the class by not hiding its creation.

And this is the result:

```
book = Book("Hello")
print(book.last_accessed)  # 2020-07-03 09:33:04.999283

book.add_content(" World")
print(book.last_accessed)  # 2020-07-03 09:33:04.999359

book.read_content()
print(book.last_accessed)  # 2020-07-03 09:33:04.999399
```

This is a simple example, and you may want to make it cleaner.

For instance, the decorator only set the `.last_accessed` attribute, but maybe you'll want to change that name easily. For that, you can use a decorator that can take arguments.

See the [Real Python Primer on Python Decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) for more insights.